# Trying to get mathjax to load on facebook to render comments

Tags: javascript, facebook, developer-tools

I have the following script which works on most blog sites (when entering in the console for the developer tools) but facebook:

```js
(function() {


  /* insert the MathJax script dynamically into the document */
  /* also insert a fix for Google+, until fixed upstream in MathJax */
  function insertScript(doc) {

    var googleFix = '.MathJax .mn {background: inherit;} .MathJax .mi {color: inherit;} .MathJax .mo {background: inherit;}';
    var style = doc.createElement('style');
    style.innerText = googleFix;
    try {
      style.textContent = googleFix;
    } catch (e) {}
    doc.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(style);

    var script = doc.createElement('script'),
      config;

    /* see http://www.mathjax.org/resources/faqs/#problem-https */
    script.src = '//cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-MML-AM_HTMLorMML.js';
    script.type = 'text/javascript';

    /* see http://docs.mathjax.org/en/v1.1-latest/options/tex2jax.html */
    config = 'MathJax.Ajax.config.path[\'Contrib\']=\'//cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/contrib\';MathJax.Hub.Config({tex2jax:{inlineMath:[[\'$\',\'$\'],[\'$$\', \'$$\']],displayMath:[[\'\\\\[\',\'\\\\]\']],processEscapes:true},TeX:{extensions: [\'[Contrib]/xyjax/xypic.js\']}});MathJax.Hub.Startup.onload();';

    if (window.opera) script.innerHTML = config;
    else script.text = config;

    doc.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
  }

  /* execute MathJax for given window */
  function executeMathJax(win) {
    if (win.MathJax === undefined) {
      /* insert the script into document if MathJax global doesn't exist for given window */
      insertScript(win.document);
    } else {
      /* using win.Array instead of [] to get 'instanceof Array' check working inside iframe */
      /* see http://www.mathjax.org/docs/1.1/typeset.html */
      win.MathJax.Hub.Queue(new win.Array('Typeset', win.MathJax.Hub));
    }
  }

  var frames = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe'),
    index, win;

  /* execute MathJax on the window object */
  executeMathJax(window);

  /* try to execute MathJax on every iframe */
  for (index = 0; index < frames.length; index++) {
    /* find the iframe's window object */
    win = frames[index].contentWindow || frames[index].contentDocument;
    if (!win.document) win = win.parentNode;

    executeMathJax(win);
  }
})();
```

When loading on facebook I get the following bug :

`Refused to load the script         'https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-MML-AM_HTMLorMML.js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src *.facebook.com *.fbcdn.net *.facebook.net *.google-analytics.com *.virtualearth.net *.google.com 127.0.0.1:* *.spotilocal.com:* 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' *.akamaihd.net *.atlassolutions.com blob: chrome-extension://lifbcibllhkdhoafpjfnlhfpfgnpldfl".`

I really cannot figure out what this is or how to circumvent it. I attempted a bug report on facebook but not sure when they will get back to me I also attempted loading the whole mathjax.js by copypasting in the console but then I would not know how to change my snippet to work with that.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_Security_Policy – Facebook simply instructs the browser not to allow embedding scripts from any domains other than the ones mentioned in the message, for security reasons. (F.e. someone might post “instructions” somewhere on the web to try and trick less experienced users into executing malicious scripts by copy&pasting script code into the console.)

Comment: Ok but I can load the whole mathjax.js in to the console is there a way for me to addapt the script to that as in the lines ```src.script = "link to math jax"```

Answer (score -3):

```js
(function() {


  /* insert the MathJax script dynamically into the document */
  /* also insert a fix for Google+, until fixed upstream in MathJax */
  function insertScript(doc) {

    var googleFix = '.MathJax .mn {background: inherit;} .MathJax .mi {color: inherit;} .MathJax .mo {background: inherit;}';
    var style = doc.createElement('style');
    style.innerText = googleFix;
    try {
      style.textContent = googleFix;
    } catch (e) {}
    doc.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(style);

    var script = doc.createElement('script'),
      config;

    /* see http://www.mathjax.org/resources/faqs/#problem-https */
    script.src = '//cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-MML-AM_HTMLorMML.js';
    script.type = 'text/javascript';

    /* see http://docs.mathjax.org/en/v1.1-latest/options/tex2jax.html */
    config = 'MathJax.Ajax.config.path[\'Contrib\']=\'//cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/contrib\';MathJax.Hub.Config({tex2jax:{inlineMath:[[\'$\',\'$\'],[\'$$\', \'$$\']],displayMath:[[\'\\\\[\',\'\\\\]\']],processEscapes:true},TeX:{extensions: [\'[Contrib]/xyjax/xypic.js\']}});MathJax.Hub.Startup.onload();';

    if (window.opera) script.innerHTML = config;
    else script.text = config;

    doc.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
  }

  /* execute MathJax for given window */
  function executeMathJax(win) {
    if (win.MathJax === undefined) {
      /* insert the script into document if MathJax global doesn't exist for given window */
      insertScript(win.document);
    } else {
      /* using win.Array instead of [] to get 'instanceof Array' check working inside iframe */
      /* see http://www.mathjax.org/docs/1.1/typeset.html */
      win.MathJax.Hub.Queue(new win.Array('Typeset', win.MathJax.Hub));
    }
  }

  var frames = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe'),
    index, win;

  /* execute MathJax on the window object */
  executeMathJax(window);

  /* try to execute MathJax on every iframe */
  for (index = 0; index < frames.length; index++) {
    /* find the iframe's window object */
    win = frames[index].contentWindow || frames[index].contentDocument;
    if (!win.document) win = win.parentNode;

    executeMathJax(win);
  }
})();
```

Comment: This is just a copy paste of my snippet